Five dollar and ten dollar denominations, or five dollars and ten dollars denominations?
If I want to tell someone to split their $100 bill into smaller denominations ($5, $10), should I tell them to split their $100 bill into "five dollar and ten dollar denominations", or "five dollars and ten dollars denominations"? I'm not sure if I should add the "s" after the two dollar denominations. Thank you!

Please, only use a capital letter for the first word of a sentence! (And for proper nouns.)

-Kate Bunting, I Know When To Use Capital Letters Kate, I Just Like Writing/Typing
Words Down  Using Capital Letters (Albeit It's Not Formal/Correct). Thanks For
The Feedback Though!

We say five-dollar and ten-dollar denominations.
The compound nouns five-dollar and ten-dollar are used as attributive nouns to modify denominations.  We normally use the singular, and I'd usually hyphenate them, as shown.

Five-pound note, two-ton weight, five-mile walk, ten-gallon hat, three-hour wait...

Thanks, @Michael Harvey, for the examples, including ten-gallon hat which I've just learned.

Three-dog night.

Thanks, @TimR.  There was a band called Three Dog Night.
